# Engineyard ey web enable command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, engineyard

I am using the engineyard gem, trying to disable the maintenace page. When I use either of the two commands:

```
ey web enable
ey web disable
```

It says "running command on deploy@..." then I get an error:
    undefined method 'ssh_type' for nil:Niclass

1) Has anyone encountered this before?
2) Does anyone know how I can take down the maintenance page without using the Engineyard gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to disable the maintenance page by removing the `/data/app_name/shared/system/maintenance.html` file or renaming it. Additionally, are you able to use `ey ssh` to successfully login to the instance? What version of the gem are you running?

Thanks,
Evan

Comment: Engineyard 2.0.11 is the version of the gem. I can't use ey ssh either, get an error that says: buffer_get: trying to get 4 more bytes than in buffer 0. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Krishna,

Can you please create a ticket at http://support.engineyard.com so we can dig deeper and take a closer look?